# Check if column exist in Laravel model's table and then apply condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Current Situation** : We are creating new database for new registration.

**Problem** : If any changes done in database migration we need to handle it for previously created database. Or run that migration for each previously created database.

If we run migration for each database no problem.

**Question** : how to check database table has column for which we are applying condition in query.

Currently I need to fire two queries first for first row and check the existence of that column and then apply condition in where clause. like below

```
$firstRow = Model::first();
if(isset($firstRow->is_splited)){
    $records = Model::where('is_splited',0)->get(); // this will give error if I don't check column existence for previously created database. 
}else{
    $records = Model::all();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve in one query. Or any better way to do it ?

---

*Thanks for your time and suggestion.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@DigitalDrifter gave an idea to use `Schema` class so I just tried like this

I Include `Schema` class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

And check column by using `Schema` class, and it also works

```
$isColExist = Schema::connection("connection_name")->hasColumn('table_name','is_splited');
$q = Acquire::with("block");
if($isColExist){
    $q->where('is_splited',0);
}
$records = $q->get();
```

Comment: @pankajkumar: Dhanbad, I mean Dhanyawad :)

Comment: ha ha ha, Dhanbad was not wrong.. I am from Dhanbad-Jharkhand. Nikesh Ji, I want to join you. please send your Mail or Wtsup for technology share. I am working on the Multiple Vendor Auth concept in Laravel. so I think you can help me. The model is already developed and being used in the project. but in want to improve this. so i am telling. send your mail in **p1608088@gmail.com** . @Niklesh where you are from?

Answer (score 21):

Late here but a simple and quick solution

```
    if (Schema::hasColumn('flights', 'departure_time')){
        // do something
      }
```

Comment: best answer as of today

Answer (score 17):

Updated solution working in 5.8

```
if ($object->getConnection()
           ->getSchemaBuilder()
           ->hasColumn($object->getTable(), 'column_name')) {
    // required update here
}
```

This solution only requires an $object and a 'column_name' to work.  The connection and table names are derived from the object itself.

Comment: This one worked for me without having to import anything.

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following to get an array of Column classes:

```
$columns = $model->getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getColumns();
```

There's also [getColumnListing](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnListing) and [hasColumn](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_hasColumn).

Comment: Wow you gave an idea.

Comment: I know it's not complete but really helped me a lot. Now I can use `in_array('col_name',$columns)`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter `Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySQLSchemaManager::getColumns()`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way that's short and works well with multiple connections (because you get it directly from the model):

```php
isset($model->attributesToArray()['column'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `fillable` and `hidden` attributes if all the columns are set there.

```
in_array(
   $column,
   array_merge($model->getFillable(), $model->getHidden()),
);
```

It worked for me ✔️